# tween library in flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, tween

I want to tween the alpha of a picture in a flex mobile app. I've tried tweenlite
but it runs too fast. Is there any optimised way of doing it, or linking in objective C
code ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the TweenLite library you can control the length of the tween, either using the number of frames or using a time length.

In your tweenProperties object, use the useFrames keyword to specify whether the tween time span specifies frames or seconds.

The second parameter of the 'to' or 'from' tweens specifies the length.

So, create an alpha tween that tweens over 10 frames, it should look like this:

```
tweenProperties = new Object();
tweenProperties.alpha = yourNewAlphaHere;
tweenProperties.useFrames = true;

TweenLite.to(myObjectToTween, 10,tweenProperties);
```

To create an alpha tween that tweens over 10 seconds, it would be like this:

```
tweenProperties = new Object();
tweenProperties.alpha = yourNewAlphaHere;
tweenProperties.useFrames = false;

TweenLite.to(myObjectToTween, 10,tweenProperties);
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to consider TweenNano for mobile apps, since it is the smallest footprint.